# How to disable flashing terminal in Mac OS

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, terminal

when i enter terminals commands etc and hit TAB (file name completion) the whole terminal window flashes rapidly (if there is no unique filename for example). This is not good since for some people this can trigger a seizure, and for me it causes really bad headaches. Is there a way we can disable this flashing?

Comment: Probably more suited to superuser.com

Answer (score 41):

Uncheck the 'visual bell' box in the preferences for your terminal style.

Comment: If that's already off, make sure you have disabled System Preferences > Universal Access > Hearing > Flash the screen when an alert sound occurs.

Answer (score 9):

This is probably not the right place to ask this question. But there is a setting for that: Settings/Advanced/Visual bell

Answer (score 7):

Step (1) - Disable Visual Bell

Terminal > Preferences > Profiles > Advanced > Bell

Uncheck the "Visual Bell"

Step (2) - When Audible Bell is still enabled and screen continues to flash

System Preferences > Accessibilty > Audio

Uncheck the "Flash screen when alert sound occurs"

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is using iTerm2 and having this problem, try going into Preferences->Profiles->Terminal and check "Silence Bell".

Answer (score 0):

If using X-term, Hold down CTRL.  Press and hold the MiddleMouse.  Move to 'Enable Visual Bell' and release the mouse button.  This would make a great community wiki...how to do it in every terminal!